# What is the difference between Parallel and Branch combinators in Trax?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, trax

I don't understand what's the difference between the [Branch](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trax.layers.html#trax.layers.combinators.Branch) and the [Parallel](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trax.layers.html#trax.layers.combinators.Parallel) combinators.
They both seem to apply a list of layers in parallel, the only difference is that Branch applies them **to copies of inputs** -- what does that mean?

Answer (score -1):

From the Trax [documentation](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trax.layers.html):

> For example, suppose one has three layers:
> F: 1 input, 1 output
> G: 3 inputs, 1 output
> H: 2 inputs, 2 outputs (h1, h2)
>
> Then Branch(F, G, H) will take 3 inputs and give 4 outputs:
> inputs: a, b, c
> outputs: F(a), G(a, b, c), h1, h2 where h1, h2 = H(a, b)
>
> Then Parallel(F, G, H) will take 6 inputs and give 4 outputs:
> inputs: a, b, c, d, e, f
> outputs: F(a), G(b, c, d), h1, h2 where h1, h2 = H(e, f)